# Grails: Invoking Domain method from gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following domain class:

```
package com.example

class Location {
   String state

    def getStatesList(){

    def states = ['AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT',
         'DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
         'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS',
         'MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC',
         'ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN',
         'TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY']
    return states
   }
}
```

In my gsp, I am trying to display the state list in a select dropdown as such

```
<g:select name="location.state" class="form-control" from="${com.example.Location?.getStatesList()}" value="${itemInstance?.location?.state}" noSelection="['': '']" />
```

In doing so, I am receiving "missing method exception"

If I change the method with list, I no longer receive the error, but I don't want that.

```
from="${com.example.Location?.list()}"    // works
from="${com.example.Location?.getStatesList()}"     // does not work
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `getStatesList()` should be declared `static` with the way you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dmahaptro said, you can correct this issue by making `getStatesList()` a static method.

```
class Location {
   String state

   static List<String> getStatesList() {
         ['AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT',
         'DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
         'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS',
         'MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC',
         'ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN',
         'TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY']
   }
}
```

Then you'll be able to execute `Location.statesList` or `Location.getStatesList()`.

## Alternative

I think a cleaner alternative is using a final *constant*:

```
class Location {
   String state

   static final List<String> STATES =
         ['AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT',
         'DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA',
         'KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS',
         'MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC',
         'ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN',
         'TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY']
}
```

Then you can access the list the same way: `Location.STATES`. The difference is that the all-caps name implies a value that does not change (and does not require accessing the database).

Answer (score 0):

list() is a method on the domain object's metaclass.  In order to do what you're trying to do you'd have to instantiate an instance of Location (or add to the metaclass).  I'd personally use an [Enum](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/23/grails-domain-classes-and-enums/) instead if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `getStatesList()` static because you are not accessing an instance of the `Location` class.